# How to use 'this.props.params' in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I send a certain id (idValue) to my component and use it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.onHandleFetch(this.props.params.idValue);
  }
```

But sometimes this component opens without any input parameters (without idValue) and I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idValue' of undefined
```

How can I fix it?

I've tried to use *typeof*, but it was unsuccessful

In the component from which the value is transferred, I use **context router**

Comment: Can can fix this by either always passing the `params` prop to the component or checking if it's there before accessing it.

Comment: Params might actually be the one who is undefined. Try logging your entire props to make sure you have the data which you are expecting.

Comment: You should provide more info like how params gets passed to your component and where it's coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static defaultProps = {
    params:{}
}
```

Comment: Code dumps aren't *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, *why*, and *how* it works, ideally with documentation links.

Comment: Thank you! I added to defaultProps "idValue: '-1'" and checking it in code using if

Answer (score 2):

The error tells us that `this.props.params` is `undefined` sometimes (probably because no `params` was passed to the component at all).

> How can I fix it?

It depends on whether you want to call `this.onHandleFetch` if there's no `params.idValue`.

If you don't, use an `if`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.params && this.props.params.idValue) {
    this.onHandleFetch(this.props.params.idValue);
  }
}
```

If you do, providing some replacement value, then:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.onHandleFetch((this.props.params && this.props.params.idValue) || replacementValue);
}
```

Both of those assume `idValue` won't be `0`.

Comment: I tried it earlier, but it didn't help me. But thank you for your help! 
I resolved my problem using "defaultProps"

Answer (score 0):

Add appropriate default props to the component where you are trying to access the params e.g.

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  params: {}
};
```

This will mean that when you try to access params from `componentDidMount()`, `this.props.params` will not be empty if you did not pass in an object for params like so when using the component.

1. with params `<MyComponent params={{ idValue: 1 }} />` will use the params passed here.
2. without params `<MyComponent />` will fallback to the defaultProps above.

You will only need to check for the presence of ID in that case to make sure that your component only makes the fetch if an `idValue` is defined in the params.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { params } = this.props;
    if (params.idValue)
        this.onHandleFetch(params.idValue);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass a default value if idValue is not defined e.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { params } = this.props;
    this.onHandleFetch(params.idValue || -1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match with what OP described.